# What does 'breakdown' mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

> The Council's ethnic and religious **breakdown** included 13 Shias, five Sunnis, five Kurds (also Sunnis), one Turkmen and an Assyrian.

It's from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraqi_Governing_Council) on Wikipedia.

update: I was wondering why "break" and "down" have anything to do with "division into categories". Or I just can't consider "breakdown" as "break" and "down" separately?

Thanks.

Comment: What dictionaries did you look the word up in? Which definition do you think might be correct? What specifically do you not understand about a definition or definitions of *breakdown* with regard to its use in this sentence?

Comment: To piggyback on what @δοῦλος is saying, we don't mind questions where you ask about the meaning of a word. However, we expect that you do some research first (dictionaries, Google, etc.), and that you also share what you found. More is explained [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), particularly under the part that says, "Show your research."

Comment: @δοῦλος I've edited the question. Sorry for asking a stupid question.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo It's not that the original question was stupid; it's more that it was beyond the purpose of this site.  In order to keep it filled with active discussion of ELL topics, straightforward questions that are answerable via a dictionary aren't desirable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A compound word like **breakdown** almost always has roots based in the two words from which it was made, but over time words gain additional meanings and can change quite dramatically.  The roots of this one are still fairly straightforward though, and we still use the words *break down* as the verb form of the noun *breakdown*.

Breakdown once meant [a collapse](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=breakdown), as in a building breaking apart and falling down.  It later took on the meaning of intentionally dismantling an object.  Boy Scouts might *break down* their tents as part of striking camp.  Taking something apart often involves categorizing the parts.  We still say that a cook *breaks down* a chicken or a fish when he or she cuts it into parts, for instance.

In much the same way, a figurative breakdown, as in your quotation, is an analysis that splits an object into its parts.